# Изменить элементы массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется массив такого вида

```
[ [ 'Alex', '167%', '45%' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', '12%', '0%' ],
  [ 'Elijah', '117%', '115%' ],
  [ 'Liam', '56%', '5%' ],
  [ 'Theodore', '135%', '114%' ],
  [ 'Mia', '128%', '100%' ] ]
```

необходимо привести его к такому виду

```
    [ [ 'Alex                167%   45%' ,
      [ 'Benjamin             12%    0%' ,
      [ 'Elijah              117%  115%' ,
      [ 'Liam                 56%    5%' ,
      [ 'Theodore            135%   14%' ,
      [ 'Mia                 128%  100%'  ]
```

т.е. мне необходимо каждому первому элементу всем вложенным массивам добавить в конце такое количество пробелов, чтобы длинна этого элемента стала ровной 18 символов, а второму и третьему элементу добавить спереди пробелы, чтобы их длинна стала равна 6 символов (итого 30 символов).

Для примера массивов с двумя элементами есть вот такой код:

```
const items = [
  ['Alex', '167%'],
  ['Benjamin', '127%'],
  ['Elijah', '117%'],
  ['Liam', '136%'],
  ['Theodore', '135%'],
  ['Mia', '128%']
];


const combined = items.map(([name, percent]) =>
  name.padEnd(29 - percent.length, ' ') + percent
);

console.log(combined);
```

как его можно модифицировать под мою задачу? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте padStart

```
let items = [ [ 'Alex', '167%', '45%' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', '12%', '0%' ],
  [ 'Elijah', '117%', '115%' ],
  [ 'Liam', '56%', '5%' ],
  [ 'Theodore', '135%', '114%' ],
  [ 'Mia', '128%', '100%' ] ]

items = items.map(
  ([name, first, second]) => name.padEnd(18, " ") + first.padStart(6, " ") + second.padStart(6, " ")
  )

items.map(item => console.log(item))
```