# Перебрать и изменить список списков

Tags: python, строки, список, форматирование

Из google-таблиц получаю данные в таком виде:

```
[['Иван', '253054', '29,84'],
 ['Александр', '246041', '28,56'],
 ['Антон', '324203', '32,02'],
 ['Дмитрий', '311052', '32,33']]
```

Далее хочу передавать эти данные через телеграм-бота в читаемом виде. Для этого необходимо первому элементу у вложенных списков (имя) в конце добавлять столько пробелов, пока их длина не станет равной 20 символам, а второму и третьему элементу добавлять пробелы спереди, пока их длина не будет равна 7 символам. В результате должно получиться как то так:

```
Иван              253054  29,84
Александр         246041  28,56
Антон             324203  32,02
Дмитрий           311052  32,33
```

[Задавал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1428434/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0) подобный вопрос по JS, там мне подсказали как это сделать

```
x = x.map(
  ([name, i, j]) => name.padEnd(15, " ") + i.padStart(7, " ") + j.padStart(7, " ") + '\n'
)
```

Теперь понадобилось сделать аналогичное на python. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это можно сделать через функции строки `ljust` и `rjust`

Пример:

```
items = [
    ['Иван', '253054', '29,84'],
    ['Александр', '246041', '28,56'],
    ['Антон', '324203', '32,02'],
    ['Дмитрий', '311052', '32,33']
]
lines = [
    name.ljust(15) + i.rjust(7) + j.rjust(7)
    for name, i, j in items
]
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Или через форматирование строк:

```
lines = [
    f'{name:<15}{i:>7}{j:>7}'
    for name, i, j in items
]
```

Результат:

```
Иван            253054  29,84
Александр       246041  28,56
Антон           324203  32,02
Дмитрий         311052  32,33
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что было нужно

Comment: @ZxNuClear, пожалуйста :)

Comment: а можешь еще вдогонку подсказать как в получившемся списке **lines** после каждого второго элемента добавить к примеру **'\n'**? Что то по аналогии с вот этим кодом **for (var i = 2; i < lines.length; i += 3) {lines.splice(i, 0, '\n');}**

Comment: @ZxNuClear, `for i in reversed(range(2, len(lines) + 1, 2)): lines.insert(i, '\n')` тут вставка с конца, т.к. при вставке элемента по порядку будет смещение индексов, возможно проще при генерации `lines` считать индексы и добавлять элементы :)